# Removing text enclosed between HTML tags using JSoup

Tags: html, text, jsoup, extract

In some cases of HTML cleaning, I would like to retain the text enclosed between the tags(which is the default behaviour of Jsoup) and in some cases, I would like to remove the text as well as the HTML tags. Can someone please throw some light on how I can remove the text enclosed between the HTML tags using Jsoup?

Comment: 6 questions and none of the accepted. Do you not appreciate the help given you here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Cleaner](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#clean%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist%29) will always drop tags and preserve text. If you need to drop elements (i.e. tags and text / nested elements), you can pre-parse the HTML, remove the elements using either [`remove()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#remove%28%29) or [`empty()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#empty%28%29), then run the resulting through the cleaner.

For example:

```java
String html = "Clean <div>Text dropped</div>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
doc.select("div").remove();

// if not removed, the cleaner will drop the <div> but leave the inner text
String clean = Jsoup.clean(doc.body().html(), Whitelist.basic());
```

If you are using JSoup 1.14.1+ then use [Safelist](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Safelist.html) instead of [Whitelist](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html), as Whitelist has been deprecated and will be removed in 1.15.1.

```java
String clean = Jsoup.clean(doc.body().html(), Safelist.basic());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1.     String html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title></head><body><p>hello there</p></body></html>";
2.      Document d = Jsoup.parse(html);
3.      System.out.println(d);
4.      System.out.println("************************************************");
5.      d.getElementsByTag("p").remove();
6.      System.out.println(d);
```

while you getting with Elements you getting some trouble you can do this action on Document d object. that will work accurate.