# Jsoup - Keep only the tags and remove all the text

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to remove all the texts between the tags of an HTML page using Jsoup

For example, if the input HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The output should be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1></h1>
<p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, I want to remove what is returned by `doc.text()`

I have found a lot of posts to do the contrary and keep only the text, but nothing to solve my problem. Any idea on how to do this?

**EDIT**

The solution proposed by maverick9999 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24292349/3589481 will solve most of the cases.

However, as noticed in comments this solution will also remove the nested tags.

As an example:

```
    String str = "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
                "<html>" +
                "<body>" +
                "<div class='foo'>text <div class='THIS DIV WILL BE REMOVED'>text</div> text </div>" +
                "<h1>My First Heading</h1>\n" +
                "<p>My first paragraph.</p>\n" +
                "</body>\n" +
                "</html>";

        Document doc=Jsoup.parse(str);
        removeAllTexts(doc);
        System.out.println(doc);

        Elements all=doc.select("*");
        Iterator<Element>iterator=all.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            Element e=iterator.next();
            if(!e.ownText().isEmpty()){
                e.text("");
            }
        }

        System.out.println(doc);
```

Will remove one div in the output:

```
    <html>
     <head></head>
     <body>
      <div class="foo">
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Any thoughts to avoid this?

**EDIT 2**

For some reason, the tag "meta" is considered as self-closing by Jsoup.
So if you have something like this:

```
System.out.println("\n\n----");
String html = "<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n"
+ "<html>\r\n"
+ "<head>\n" 
+ "<meta content=\"/myimage.png\" itemprop=\"image\">\n"
+ "<title>Title</title>\n" 
+ "<script>Random Javascript here</script>"
+ "</meta>"
+ "</head>"
+ "<body>\r\n"
+ "<h1>My First <i>Heading</i></h1>\r\n"
+ "<hr/>\r\n"
+ "<p>My first paragraph.</p>\r\n"
+ "<p> <div class='foo'>text <div class='bar'> text </div> text </div> </p>\r\n"
+ "</body>\r\n" 
+ "</html>";

Document doc2 = Jsoup.parse(html,"",Parser.xmlParser());
printNodes(doc2);
```

Then all the tags after `meta` will not be read. With Pshemo solution, the scripts are removed and if you have `br` tags with children (for example), they will be removed as well. 
I finally ended up with the following solution (thanks to Pshemo for his help):

```
   public static void printNodes(Node node) {
        String name = node.nodeName();
        if (name.equals("#doctype")) {
            System.out.println(node);
        } else if (name.equals("#text")) {
            return;
        } else if (name.equals("#document")) {
            for (Node n : node.childNodes())
                printNodes(n);
        } 
        // There is no reason to have text here, so print everything
        else if (name.equals("head") || name.equals("script")){
            System.out.println(node.toString());
        }
        else {
            if (!Tag.valueOf(name).isSelfClosing() || node.childNodeSize()>0) {
                System.out.println("<" + name + getAttributes(node) + ">");
                for (Node n : node.childNodes())
                    printNodes(n);
                System.out.println("</" + name + ">");
            } else {
                // System.out.println("debug: " + name + " is self closing");
                System.out.println("<" + name + getAttributes(node) + "/>");
            }
        }
    }

   public static String getAttributes(Node node) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Attribute attr : node.attributes()) {
            sb.append(" ").append(attr.getKey()).append("=\"")
                    .append(attr.getValue()).append("\"");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738762/removing-text-enclosed-between-html-tags-using-jsoup

Comment: The problem with the methods `empty` and `remove` is that they remove the entire node (Tag and content)

Comment: Is it possible that your text will have some nested tags like `<div class='foo'>text <div class='bar'>text</div> text </div>` because accepted solution will remove also `<div class='bar'>text</div>` from `<div class='foo'>`.

Comment: I have not noticed that, that is an excellent observation. I will edit my first post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The below code should solve your problem with nested tags:

Updated code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());

for (Element el : doc.select("*")){
    if (!el.ownText().isEmpty()){
        for (TextNode node : el.textNodes())
            node.remove();
    }
}

System.out.println(doc);
```