# Jsoup remove ONLY html tags

Tags: java, html, tags, jsoup, strip

What is proper way to remove ONLY html tags (preserve all custom/unknown tags) with JSOUP (NOT regex)?

Expected input:

```
<html>
  <customTag>
    <div> dsgfdgdgf </div>
  </customTag>
  <123456789/>
  <123>
  <html123/>
</html>
```

Expected output:

```
  <customTag>
     dsgfdgdgf
  </customTag>
  <123456789/>
  <123>
  <html123/>
```

I tried to use Cleaner with WhiteList.none(), but it removes custom tags also.

Also I tried:

```
String str = Jsoup.parse(html).text()
```

But it removes custom tags also.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738762/removing-text-enclosed-between-html-tags-using-jsoup) isn't good for me, because number of custom tags is infinity.

Comment: No complete recipe but you might want to check the html sanitizer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to try something like this:

```
String[] tags = new String[]{"html", "div"};
Document thing = Jsoup.parse("<html><customTag><div>dsgfdgdgf</div></customTag><123456789/><123><html123/></html>");
for (String tag : tags) {
    for (Element elem : thing.getElementsByTag(tag)) {
        elem.parent().insertChildren(elem.siblingIndex(),elem.childNodes());
        elem.remove();
    }
}
System.out.println(thing.getElementsByTag("body").html());
```

Please note that <123456789/> and <123> don't conform to the xml standard, so they get escaped. Another downside may be that you have to explicitly write down all tags you don't like (aka all html tags) and it may be sloooooow. Haven't looked at how fast this is going to run.

MFG
MiSt

Comment: I thought about solution like your but I want something generic.

Comment: what do you mean with 'generic'?

Comment: Another thought: Cleaners don't implement Blacklist-filtering because they are prone to attacks, because someone happened to forget something or the standard gets a new attackable tag. Therefore you most likely need to implement one yourself. JSoup doesn't provide that...

Comment: It inserts a `<br>` tag in front of every `HTML` tag in the string