# Jsoup parser remove words with '<' and '>'

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm using the `Jsoup.parse()` to remove html tags from a String. But my string as a word like `<name>` also.

The problem is Jsoup.parse() remove that too. I'ts because that text has < and >. I can't just remove < and > from the text too. How can I do this.

```
String s1 = Jsoup.parse("<p>Hello World</p>").text();
//s1 is "Hello World". Correct

String s2 = Jsoup.parse("<name>").text();
//s2 is "". But it should be <name> because <name> is not a html tag
```

Comment: <name> is a tag unless the `<` and `>` are escaped.

Comment: is there any way to parse html with only selected tags. like <p>,<a>,<b>,<i>,etc

Answer (score -1):

> I'm using the Jsoup.parse() to remove html tags from a String.

You want to use the [Jsoup#clean](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#clean-java.lang.String-org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist-) method. You'll also need a little manual work after because Jsoup will still see `<name>` as an HTML tag.

```
// Define the list of words to preserve...
String[] myExceptions = new String[] { "name" }; 
int nbExceptions = myExceptions.length;

// Build a whitelist for Jsoup...
Whitelist myWhiteList = Whitelist.simpleText().addTags(myExceptions);

// Let Jsoup remove any html tags...
String s2 = Jsoup.clean("<name>", myWhiteList);

// Complete the initial html tags removal...
for (int i = 0; i < nbExceptions; i++) {
    s2 = s2.replaceAll("<" + myExceptions[i] + ">.+?</" + myExceptions[i] + ">", "<" + myExceptions[i] + ">");
}

System.out.println(">>" + s2);
```

#### OUTPUT

```
>><name>
```

#### References

- [How to remove HTML tags from a string with Jsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34588376/363573)
- [Whitelist javadoc](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html)
- [clean method javadoc](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#clean-java.lang.String-org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist-)

Comment: This wont work because Jsoup is adding the trailing </name> after the text node.  Consider this:   <p>Hello <name> World</p>....you end up with Hello <name> World </name>

Comment: Best thing to do is to escape the special characters.

Comment: @ZackTeater Thanks for signaling the issue. I have corrected it.

Comment: Yes, but still using regex on HTML content is not a practical solution.  Ideally the whitelist data should be encoded prior to parsing. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1176178